# gmplayer can't run

Tags: 20.04, video, mplayer, gmplayer

Everything seems to be installed:

```
$ apt list mplayer\*
Listing... Done
mplayer-doc/focal,focal 2:1.3.0-8build5 all
mplayer-gui/focal,now 2:1.3.0-8build5 amd64 [installed]
mplayer-skin-blue/focal,focal 1.11-2 all
mplayer-skins/focal,focal,now 3.2build1 all [installed,automatic]
mplayer/focal,now 2:1.3.0-8build5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

but when I run `gmplayer`, I see "Error in skin config file at line 6":

[image]

That file actually doesn't exist (There is one called `main.png` though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an old issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1218510) that I thought had been resolved? However I can confirm that it occurs on my 20.04 system as well. The fix is easy enough and is drawn from the linked bug report:

First install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then convert all the png files in the 'default' skin directory to the correct format. Change to this directory as follows:

```
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default
```

And then run the following loop:

```
for FILE in *.png
do
sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE
done
```

This resolved the issue on my system and should also work on yours...