# Does gmplayer work?

Tags: command-line, mplayer, gmplayer

I'm trying to get "gmplayer" to work.  I did, eventually, get it to work, but it was a struggle, and I have a question (at the end of this post).  Note: I first installed mplayer and it works just fine.  That worked "out of the box".  But when I installed mplayer-gui, then I had problems getting gmplayer working.

First, I was getting the error described at [gmplayer can't run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319473/gmplayer-cant-run) which boils down to doing (as root):

```
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default
for FILE in *.png
do
    convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE
done
```

Note: `convert` is from ImageMagick.

But it still would not run.  I get the following error message repeated infinitely until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>:

```
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then consult the man page and work out that I need to specify the video driver using the `-vo` switch.  When I add: `-vo xv`
to the gmplayer command line, it works (still generates a bunch of warnings/errors on the terminal screen, but it does work) and I am able to watch the video and use the GUI interface to control mplayer.  Yey!

But now I am wondering where the `libvpau_i965` library comes from and if I can install it to make the error go away (i.e., so that it will work without `-vo xv`).

I do:

```
apt-file search libvpau_i965.so
```

and it doesn't find anything.  So, that file doesn't seem to be in any of my sources for apt-getting.  Any idea as to where to find it?

Edit to add:

I've also noticed that there is no command line or config file option to set the playback volume.  gmplayer always defaults to (i.e., starts up as) zero volume, which is annoying.  mplayer usually defaults to whatever the volume last was.

Anyway, here is a workaround script for gmplayer to set the volume up on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -r "$1" ] || exec echo "Not found: $1"
{ sleep 3;xdotool type '***********************************************'; } &
gmplayer "$1"
```

Comment: Long running bugs, possible solution here --> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau/+bug/1300215/comments/42

Comment: Try adding `vo=xv` to `~/.mplayer/config` and this error will vanish...

Comment: Yes, but that (adding it to a config file) is the same thing as putting it on the command line.   The goal here is to understand why it needs libvdpau and where to get it, so that I don't have to do the "xv" thing.  One might call it an academic pursuit.   I will check out the other poster's suggestion about "Long running bugs".

Comment: I read the "Long running bugs" link.  It seems to me that if that .so file were available as an "apt-get install", it would have shown up in "apt-file search", so I'm leary about installing any other libraries.